# System does not boot up without connected to external monitor via HDMI

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 16.04

yesterday I just updated Ubuntu Gnome from 15.10 to 16.04. I have an external monitor connected to my Asus G55VW notebook via HDMI. After the update there weren't any problems until today, when I brought out my notebook from my room (unplugged HDMI). When I turned it on and after selecting "Ubuntu" on the Grub screen, the notebooks screen starts to flicker and nothing happens.

After a few trying I brought it back to my room, connected to my external monitor and the system booted up. I turned off the second screen in the Display menu, but it didn't help. I changed the nvidia driver back to version 340 from 36x, but it didn't help neither.

So at this moment I can only use my notebook with an external monitor. Interesting is, that when the screen flickers and I connect it to the monitor, the system boots up automatically, without restarting.

Notebook config:
CPU: Intel Core i7-3610QM
GPU: nvidia 660M GTX,
RAM: 8GB
SSD: SanDisk U100 128GB

Does anyone here have a possible solution for this? I already opened a ticket here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1574060 maybe its an nvidia bug or something, but maybe here someone will help me out too.

Comment: Having roughly the same issue but on a laptop with an AMD APU. I login via the external monitor and then hit the display hotkey (fn + f4) to turn on the laptop screen. Unfortunately that hotkey doesn't work unless I've logged-in via the external monitor first. I can play with the display settings all I want then but it will be the same issue with each reboot.

Answer (score 0):

After regular updating my ubuntu I had issue with external monitor, but it may help you to see how to fixed it, there was no output in my HDMI monitor, no matter what I tried, changed the monitor and cable several times.

here's how I solved it:

I tried to boot using HDMI and it fixed everything!

inside BIOS I changed 'boot display' to HDMI

It may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I searched for 'boot display' in my BIOS, but I couldn't find it. Anyway, I think this is an Ubuntu bug which needs to be fixed by the devs, so lets hope they find a solution for this soon.

Comment: sorry to hear that didn't find it, this is not only ubuntu problem, my friends have the same problem with fedora too! so this may be a shared package in linux systems!