# Ubuntu 16.04 powers off when I unplug hdmi cable

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-management, shutdown, hdmi

There is a strange problem with my fresh Ubuntu installation. I installed it to my laptop which also has an external display connected via hdmi cable. If I unplug the hdmi cable, after 1-2 seconds, the laptop powers off (not normal shutdown). Do you have any ideas where to search for the problem? Thanks, Mike

UPDATE:
This is the content of syslog:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd6ed331b891e0a68657d65c887e2583

It is quite long, so i wanted to make a shorter one. I deleted syslog file and created again with touch. I started a `tail -f syslog` and unplugged the cable again, but nothing happened.
 I stopped the tail process and tried again, but the laptop didn't power off.
After reboot, the problem came back. The new syslog is empty.

UPDATE2:
I've reinstalled the whole system without external monitor. At first the installer quited, but for the second time I could install the system again. I've found a similar issue here ([System does not boot up without connected to external monitor via HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763084/system-does-not-boot-up-without-connected-to-external-monitor-via-hdmi?rq=1)). I also have an i7 processor, but every other hardware is different. I think I will just choose Win7 again.

UPDATE3:
I decided to use Ubuntu inside a virtual machine, because it solved my problem and a good option for me.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! By "it powers off" do you mean the laptop? IF so, what is the content of  `/var/log/syslog` for the moment in time that you unplug the hdmi cable? I'm sorry but I'm not clear on what you are asking here. Would you be so kind as to review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and then [edit] pertinant info into your question? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Exactly. Here is the syslog from yesterday, starting from when I unplugged the cable: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd6ed331b891e0a68657d65c887e2583

It is quite long, so i wanted to make a shorter one. I deleted syslog and created again with touch. I started a
`tail -f syslog`
and unplugged the cable again, but nothing happened. I stopped the process and tried again, but the laptop didn't power off.

Comment: **Update**  
After restart, the problem came back. The syslog didn't change.

Comment: Please [edit] new information into your post as I requested. Comments can be deleted for various reasons and may not be read by everyone. This can make it hard for others on the team to determine what the status is. (Reducing your odds of an answer).

Comment: "Every other hardware is different doesn't tell us anything useful. Please [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -C display` and `uname -a` intoyour post. Thank you for helping us help you! If you are getting variable results installing from the same live media that leads me to wonder if you went so far as to [check the iso](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788) and the status of your drive(http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10/528077)

Comment: You might also shed some light on your situation by booting [memtest86+](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu) and [testing your ram](http://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502)

Comment: I wrote "every other hardware is different" because the probability of having the same driver problem with different hardware is quite low, but of course, who knows..  
I tested the iso right after the download, it was ok. I checked the ram and my ssd's smart values, everything seems ok. It can be the problem of my usb stick, but I didn't have more time for experiments, so I switched back to windows 7 and installed ubuntu in a virtual machine, it behaves normally now.    
Thank you for your help and time.